# Use custom field from custom object in class

Tags: apex, custom-object, class, custom-field

I am creating an `Apex Class` using eclipse and trying to use a field.

I have created a custom object called `Credit_Insurance__c` and a custom field named `Credit_Insurance_Status_c`.

When I  try to use the field in my class, I get an error saying that the 
variable doesn't exist.

I have tried the field api name and `object_api_name.field_api_name`.
I'm sure it's name syntax.

Comment: could you add line, how you are using this field?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply get metadata for the field, there are a few different pieces of information you can get.

```
Schema.SObjectField myCustomField = Credit_Insurance__c.Credit_Insurance_Status__c;
DescribeFieldResult describe = myCustomField.getDescribe();
```

If you want to get data, you need a `Credit_Insurance__c` record to get the data from.

```
Credit_Insurance__c record = new Credit_Insurance__c(); // instantiate as desired
String status1 = record.Credit_Insurance_Status__c;
String status2 = (String)record.get(myCustomField));
String status3 = (String)record.get('Credit_Insurance_Status__c');
```

With a checkbox, it would be:

```
if (record.Validation1__c) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you simply forgot the `__c` for customfields and -objects.
You need to access your object like this:

```
Credit_Insurance__c myCi = new Credit_Insurance__c;

// you still need to query for the object or set initial values and insert it later, if you create a new one

if (myCi.Credit_Insurance_Status__c == true ) {
  // your logic here
}
```

be aware, that your snipped with one single `=` wont work, because it trys to assign the value to the field.